# add booking feature in drupal commerce

Tags: commerce, bookings

In drupal commerce, I would like to add booking feature if the product is not available for now. If the product is not available for now, I want to allow user to make booking of this product, I also want to reply email to user as soon as the product is available. Does drupal commerce support for booking? Any suggestion, pls!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try these modules :
[Commerce Waitlist](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/itamar/1772176)
 or [Commerce Stock Notifications](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stock_notifications)
They allow send notifications if product available again. As for possibility for user to reserve product in stock: without custom module such feature,I think, cannot be realized.